# Unable to connect after configuring nginx

Tags: nginx

I am currently going through the Test Driven Development book and am trying to follow it closely as possible. But once I restart nginx and try to connect to the site, all I get is a unable to connect error. I set up my nginx sites-available as:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name superlists-staging.ottg.eu;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing the localhost to 127.0.0.1 so it becomes

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name superlists-staging.ottg.eu;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Edit:I should have mentioned, the DNS name superlist-staging.ottg.eu is from the book I am working on, I have replaced it with my own DNS name.

Edit2: It was a file in my nginx sites available, not nginx.conf which the code is from.

Comment: In my nginx conf file, I have `server_name localhost;`.

Comment: Does your DNS points `superlists-staging.ottg.eu` to your host?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Yes, and it worked properly before I messed with nginx.conf. It showed the default nginx screen, now nothing.

Comment: Well, I see “Start a new To-Do list” there.

Comment: Why do you think that “nothing” is nginx fault? Could it be that your app just returns nothing. Check logs.

Comment: @AlexeyTen I forgot to mention that the DNS name is actually from the book, I have replaced it with my own. When I run the app on my computer it works fine, with the same settings. Yet when run on Amazon Web Services with nginx configured nothing happens. Also before I config nginx, I at least got the nginx default screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx config not setup correctly. Move your site config to /etc/nginx/conf.d/ directory

then restart nginx.

Please check nginx.conf file and check is this line their

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
```